# How can I subtract correctly?

Tags: c

I try to subtract multiple numbers, but this code won't give me the correct result, how can I change it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int nnr, i, nr[100], rez;

    rez = 0;
    printf("\nHow many numbers do you want to subtract?\n");
    scanf("%d", &nnr);

    printf("\nWrite the numbers:\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= nnr; i++) {
        printf("%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &nr[i]);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= nnr; i++) {
        rez += nr[i] - rez;
    }

    printf("\nResult: %d\n", rez);
}
```

Comment: What is the `correct result`?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your input? What’s the result? What should be the result? Have you run the code in a debugger line by line to see what’s happening?

Comment: Sorry for that. Well, for example, look here https://gyazo.com/3476298dafdcce322f65c815bdd99636.
2 - 5 - 7 = -10, but there the result is "7". I want the program to subtract each number from the first to the last, and print the result.

Comment: Also, check return values of scanf (always...), and do something like abort on parse errors.

Comment: `rez += nr[i] - rez;` --> `rez = rez  + nr[i] - rez;` --> `rez = nr[i];` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You clarify in comments that when given three input numbers consisting of 2, 5, and 7, you want the program to perform the computation `2 - 5 - 7` and print the result.  But your code is just wrong for that.

Here's the key part:

> ```
>     rez = 0;
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> ```
>     for(i = 1; i <= nnr; i++) {
>         rez += nr[i] - rez;
>     }
> ```

That gives you

- `rez = 0 + 2 - 0` (= 2)
- `rez = 2 + 5 - 2` (= 5)
- `rez = 5 + 7 - 5` (= 7)

In fact, we can generalize that to recognize that a construct of form `x += y - x` is roughly equivalent to `x = y`, but subject to a risk of arithmetic overflow.

Apparently, you want instead expressions of the form `rez -= nr[i]` (equivalently: `rez = rez - nr[i]`), except for the very first number, for which you want `rez = nr[i]`.  How you actually implement that is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

1) start your loops consistently at 0

2) use <`nnr`

Answer (score 1):

It's really awesome how a trivial thing as this can pose so many cases where bugs may come.

- No check for `scanf` return type. Check the return value of `scanf`.
- Also you need to check whether subtraction will results in overflow.
- Check whether the inputted number won't make you access array index out of bound.
- We generally use loping from `0` index. Convention as well as easier to use (saves you from stepping over the array bounds).
- First iteration the value of rez will be the `nr[0]` and after that you can subtract other numbers.

---

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < nnr; i++){
   if(!i) rez = nr[i];
   else
      rez = rez - nr[i];
}
```

This will give you `2-5-7 = -10`.

Also yes, you can pull out the check `if(!i)` outside the for loop and then for `nnr-1` number just subtract corresponding elements. Benefit ? saving `nnr-1` comparisons by doing this.

Comment: Or to avoid the `if` statement in the loop, use `rez = nr[0];` before the loop and start the loop at 1 instead of 0 (the loop condition `i < nnr` will remain the same). This avoids the `if (!i)` check completely for the `nnr-1` numbers entered that are not at index 0.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune.: Yes edit was needed. Done.